# Raster Calculation with Rasters of Different Extent using Rasterio

Tags: python, raster-calculator, extents, rasterio

I am looking for a way to perform raster calculations with two DEMs using rasterio. Basically, what the 'QGIS Raster Calculator' does.
My problem is, that they do not have the same extent. Therefore, simple calculations with arrays don't work. Apart from that, they have the same CRS and resolution.

What i am looking for, is a way to expand the 'smaller' raster to the extent of the 'larger' so reading them into an array gives me overlapping arrays i can calculate with.

I've already looked into windowed reading, but that didn't get me were i wanted. Also building a VRT like suggested [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31218/raster-algebra-in-python-with-rasters-of-different-extents) could work, but i think there should be a more straight-forward way...

[image: Two DEMs to perform raster calculations]

Put very simply, here's what i want to do:

```
import rasterio as rio

dhm = rio.open(os.path.join(path_in, file_in_dhm))
tf = rio.open(os.path.join(path_in, file_in_tf))

arr_dhm = dhm.read(1)
arr_tf = tf.read(1)

result = arr_dhm - arr_tf
```

But that gives me - of course - an error:

> operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10561,16101)
> (7628,11309)

Comment: "I've already looked into windowed reading, but that didn't get me were i wanted"-- why not?  That's how I'd do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think creating a [window from the bounds](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.windows.html#rasterio.windows.from_bounds) of the larger raster then using that window with [`boundless=True` to read](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.io.html#rasterio.io.DatasetReader.read) the smaller raster should work.

Something like:

```
window = rasterio.windows.from_bounds(*larger_ds.bounds, transform=smaller_ds.transform)
smaller_array = smaller_ds.read(window=window, boundless=True)
```

Comment: For some reason, when I do this and plot the updated 'smaller_array' equivalent, it looks like its extent has been properly expanded. However, when I go to add the two arrays together, it appears they are still not the same dimensions. Both raster datasets are the exact same projection. Not sure what is going on!

Comment: Set a `fill_value` perhaps? https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.io.html#rasterio.io.DatasetReader.read